# Mirror modifiers and multiple Textures

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

I would like to mirror textures independently. I know using flip U or V in mirror modifier does the job but it flips all textures. I would like to know if we can mirror textures independently without affecting other textures.

[image]

[Note: The above image is the mirrored side]

I would like to only flip the logo and not the doors and windows.

Comment: maybe there is a better solution, but couldn't you mirror the texture in an image editing software such as Gimp or PS so that the mirror modifier mirrors it back to its original orientation?

Comment: @Jonas Texture orientation is correct on the other side. This is mirrored side I want only the logo to come to a proper orientation on this[Mirrored] side

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered that problem while modeling my aircrafts. There are two possible solutions:

1. The first option is to duplicate the surface where you will put the
   logo then separate it into a different object. After that, move or
   scale it just above you main object to remove intersections of
   meshes. you can now put the logo (make sure it has a transparent
   background) and reverse since it is now an individual object and it
   will not affect other textures.
2. The last option is to apply the *Mirror* modifier then create a new
   material just the same as on the other side but the logo that you
   will now input into your image texture is reversed. This will be the
   texture that you will put apply in the mirrored side of you
   aircraft.